# Mongo C# driver - Contains Filter

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, mongodb-csharp-2.0

I am using the latest version of Mongo C# driver which uses a lot of Async and builder pattern. Which is nice. I am trying to convert SQL where clauses into Mongo FilterDefinition object.

Any idea how to handle "contains"?
like:

```
where x contains 'ABC'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `x` is a string, you could do so with a simple regex. For the 2.0 driver, you can manually create the `FilterDefinition`:

```
FilterDefinition<BsonDocument> filter = "{ x : { $regex : /ABC/ } }";
```

Or build the filter use the `Builder`:

```
var builder = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter;
var filter = builder.Matches("x", "ABC");
```

Then you can use the filter in your query:

```
using (var cursor = await collection.Find(filter).ToCursorAsync())
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks!

I am using 2.0 version of driver and could not .Matches() on Filter Builder, but I could find .Regex(), so I'll try with that.

Answer (score 19):

In order to achieve that in V2 API, use the `Filter.Regex':

```
var collection = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("collection");

var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Regex("fieldName", new BsonRegularExpression(".*fieldValue.*"));

var data = await (await coll.FindAsync<BsonDocument>(filter).ConfigureAwait(false)).ToListAsync();

//continue process data
```

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get this working using Filter.AnyIn like so

```
var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.AnyIn("x", new List<string> { "ABC" });
```

This works if you're looking for multiple values too, just add them to the list.

Answer (score 1):

First, I highly recommend taking [MongoDB University's .NET course](https://university.mongodb.com/courses/M101N/about) (from Mongo itself). It's really thorough, and covers your question (and more) in depth.

Second, I assume that `x` is an array in your example.

MongoDB correctly handles polymorphism with arrays. If you have a class `Post` with an array of `Tags`, you can filter where `Tag = ABC`.

If you're using the C# linq methods, that looks like `.Find(p => p.Tags == "ABC")`. If you're using `BsonDocument`, that looks like `new BsonDocument().Add("Tags", "ABC")`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to just search input `text` you need to replace regex special characters.

`Regex.Escape` will ensure that these characters are processed literally rather than as metacharacters. Otherwise input `text` can be used to query regex patterns which is probably not what is required.

```
var text = "ABC";
var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Regex("x", BsonRegularExpression.Create(Regex.Escape(text)));
```

If you need case insensitive check. Then you can pass case insensitive regex to `BsonRegularExpression.Create`:

```
var text = "ABC";
var escapeText = Regex.Escape(text);
var regex = new Regex(escapeText, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Regex("x", BsonRegularExpression.Create(regex));
```

Answer (score 0):

I have another way which I don't love but it works. The answer that is marked correct is half wrong (Matches is a method of Builders). In this example the / act like a % in a sql query LIKE statement. I'm still looking for a better way and will update if I find one that is more Equals filter below.

```
List<yourobject> someList = await collection.Find("{ x: /Test/ }").ToListAsync();

var filter = Builders<yourobject>.Filter.Eq("x", "ABC");
List<yourobject> someList = await collection.Find(filter).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Your builder method for the filter isn't correct. It cannot be Equal to since you're looking for Contains.